# Seedstack - MQTT Add-on problem adding user & pasword

Tags: mqtt, add-on, seedstack

I try to connect to MQTT server and I have some problems adding the password:

The configuration file is:

```
mqtt:
  clients:
    client-ptl-mqtt: 
      serverUri: tcp://rdabeg01.inetpsa.com:1883
      clientId: LOCAL_PTL_SIMUL_MQTT
      connection:
        userName: xxxxxx
        password: xxxxxxx
      reconnectionMode: ALWAYS
```

And the error when i try to start the application is:

> org.seedstack.coffig.internal.ConfigurationException: [CONFIGURATION]
>   Illegal conversion
>
> Description
>   ----------- Cannot convert to char(char.java:1): 'xxxxxxx'.
>
> ### Stacktrace
>
> ```
>     at org.seedstack.coffig.internal.ConfigurationException.createNew(ConfigurationException.java:30)
>     at org.seedstack.coffig.mapper.ValueMapper.charOf(ValueMapper.java:63)
>     at org.seedstack.coffig.mapper.ValueMapper.map(ValueMapper.java:51)
>     at org.seedstack.coffig.mapper.CompositeMapper.map(CompositeMapper.java:50)
>     at org.seedstack.coffig.mapper.EvaluatingMapper.map(EvaluatingMapper.java:65)`
> ```

Answer (score 1):

SeedStack MQTT addon relies on Paho which has a configuration class for the client connection [MqttConnectOptions](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttConnectOptions.html). The password field expects a char array, which the addon does not alter. Your YAML modified accordingly :

```
mqtt:
  clients:
    client-ptl-mqtt: 
      serverUri: tcp://rdabeg01.inetpsa.com:1883
      clientId: LOCAL_PTL_SIMUL_MQTT
      connection:
        userName: xxxxxx
        password: [ 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd' ]
      reconnectionMode: ALWAYS
```